# Plotting one-many function in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file that looks like:

```
    a               b                     c                   d
9.91804289    0.32890611E-04        2.253113185e-08    2.858389795e-08
9.91804289    0.32890611E-04        2.253113185e-08    2.858389795e-08
9.89517766    0.32597535E-04        2.255018344e-08    2.742542369e-08
9.86882582    0.33125571E-04        2.251589285e-08    2.650318558e-08
```

Now, all b,c and d are functions of a. However, b varies a lot as a function of a (and attains the same value at various different a).
I need to plot c and d as a function of b. But due to this variation of b (basically its one-many nature), I have unwanted branches in the c and d plots. Is there any way in gnuplot where I can plot it the way I want by setting the xrange using a only?

Comment: Could you please describe in more detail what it is you are trying to plot? Do you want to select only a subset of lines from your data file in which a falls wihtin a given range?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. And for that purpose I want to select it using the range of values in column a while using the data in column b as the x-axis and c & d on y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look `help using` for how to filter your input data. If you want to select only those rows in your datafile where the value of the first column is between `amin` and `amax`, you could do something like

```
amin=9.8
amax=9.9
plot "filename.dat" using 2:(($1 > amin && $1 < amax ) ? $3 : NaN) title "c" with points, \
     "" using 2:(($1 > amin && $1 < amax ) ? $4 : NaN) title "d" with points
```

Comment: Wow! It works.. Can you add in one little comment explaining what's the function of NaN here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: NaN stands for "Not a Number", which tells gnuplot to simple not draw any data points for which the condition `($1 > amin && $1 < amax )` is `false`. Instead of `Nan` you can also use `1/0` or something similar.

Comment: Take a look at `help ternary`, which explains this construct.